# Issues with Windows Store ListView Control

Tags: .net, windows, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I need some expert help on Listview in Windows store app 8.1. Currently I'm displaying 150 items in Listview vertically, with default properties set to enable like

IsSwipeEnabled="True" IsTapEnabled="True"  SelectionMode="Single"   CanDragItems="True" CanReorderItems="True"

With The above setting, everything is fine,
When the screen loads, i see First item in listview is selected by default, how can i remove the default selection. I set seletedindex =-1 and selecteditem=null, nuthing has worked.

When i set SelectionMode = "none" IsTapEnabled= False and IsItemClickEnabled="True"  then 
i don't see first item getting selected.But  now I touch events are not firing.

second issue is My list view items are draggable, every time when i select/tap an item and drag on to right side of grid. My entire Listview floats or moves , i want to make Listview fixed in position, should not get dragged the  entire listview when i drag single ListViewItem. this is causing annoy to the user . I want listview to be fixed i.e it should not move @ time the item is selected and dragged. Please provide me some suggestions on this.

```
    <SemanticZoom x:Name="semanticZoom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="4"   HorizontalAlignment="Left"    Style="{x:Null}"
              >
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
            <GridView  IsItemClickEnabled="False"  IsSwipeEnabled="False"     ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False"  Style="{x:Null}">
                 <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <ItemsWrapGrid ItemWidth="75" Orientation="Horizontal" ItemHeight="75" MaximumRowsOrColumns="5"  Background="Transparent" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
             </GridView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <ListView x:Name="ItemsGridView" IsSwipeEnabled="True"  SelectionMode="Single" IsTapEnabled="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  MaxHeight="725"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GrpColumns},Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              Height="Auto"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  AllowDrop="True"     Drop="ItemsGridView_Drop"
             Tag="{Binding Path=Columns,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"   CanDragItems="True" CanReorderItems="True" IsItemClickEnabled="True"   >
                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:DragBehaviour/>
                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid  Margin="10,2,0,2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"     >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="97*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock   Text="{StaticResource AsterikGlyph}"  
                                             Style="{StaticResource GlyphIconStyle}"   Margin="0,2,0,0"   
                                             FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                Visibility="{Binding Path=IsRequireField,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Converter={StaticResource TextBlockVisibityConverter}}" />

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SrcName}"  TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"  Margin="2,0,0,2" TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                                   Style="{StaticResource SemantizZoomOutViewTextBlock}"  Grid.Column="1"       ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding SrcName}"                                     
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>          
                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>                               
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border Background="#333F50" Margin="4" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" Width="60" Height="60">
                                    <Button x:Name="HeaderButton"  Background="Transparent" Width="60" Height="60"  Padding="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="HeaderButton_Click">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="2"  Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                                    </Button>   
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>                               
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>
            </ListView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
    </SemanticZoom>
```

Comment: Please check an answer or add more help to us

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a bind to the ListView's selected item to a property with getter and setter. Take a break point into the setter and you can check in the call stack the reason of setting default. Cause As I know there is no default selection on ListView.

With the second question, can I check you ListView and it's parents? At Codepact or something like that.

Comment: I dont have bind to SelectedItem. as you said there is no default selection is that reason for selection of default value